# Is is possible to show the service logs of only running Docker Swarm containers?

Tags: docker, logging, swarm

Currently the `docker service logs` command shows logs of all services, also the ones that already terminated. The logs are not guaranteed to be displayed in chronological order.
Is it possible to somehow hide the logs of containers which have been terminated?

The problem is that after doing
`docker service update --force my_service`
the `docker service logs` command shows logs which are sorted by the time and service name, and the logs from newly started containers may appear before the logs from the terminated containers.